# Name or service not known [tcp://redis:6379]

Tags: php, laravel-5, predis, phpredis, redis-cache

i am having a problem setting up redis cache with laravel.
i have a redis server runnig on my local machine:

[image]

my .env:

[image]

i have the localhost on port 6379 ready and listened:

[image]

someone plz tell me what's happenig here?[image]

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Change `REDIS_HOST=redis` to
`REDIS_HOST=localhost`, it is looking for a host named `redis` and not finding it, since redis is installed on the same machine you should use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Once you've done this, make sure you reload the .env config - `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: allready tried it with localhost and 127.0.0.1 with no luck!!

Comment: the odd thing is even with **REDIS_HOST=localhost** or **REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1** it's still searching for **tcp://redis:6379**

Comment: You’re running your app and redis on the same machine, correct?

Comment: yes i am runnig the app and redis from the same machine

Comment: now that's what am talking about!! **php artisan config:clear** did the trick..thank you man you'r freaking awesome!!!

Comment: This was not enough for me. Apparently I also needed to run `php artisan queue:restart`.

Comment: Make sure to update REDIS_HOST on your .env file as well (@oajmi)

Answer (score -1):

I've added this to my /etc/hosts and it fixed  the error

127.0.0.1 redis

Laradoc + laravel (5.6)